# How to read and write from character "xxx" to character "yyy" in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to pull data from a text file. Inside, each student record consists of 20-30 lines.  I'm trying to pull the pertinent information on each student - and then put it in excel.
I can pull in the student info - because they are tagged with Name:, ID#, etc.

I figured out how to open the text file and pull the data with tags and write it to another text file.  But there is a chunk (variable number of lines) that I also need for each student - and can't figure out how to read them and write.

For each student, first line always starts with "Ref No"...then some lines and later it ends with "======".   I can't figure out how to read starting at Ref No and write all the lines to the text file until I reach =====. And then move on to the next students record.

Adding text sample
Name: john smith
ID: 1234456
Amount Due: $0.00
Ref No   Date    Code   Charges  Payment   Balance
001234   12/6/18  BA     123.00   0        123.00
002345   12/7/18  DE    1000.00  1000.00   0
                Total:   1123.00 1000.00   123.00
                         ======== ======= =======
Name: Sally Smith
ID  etc

Everything works until you get to the area commented out:

```
outfile = open('Output.txt', 'w')
with open('ARSP_MGRIFFIT_3728.txt','r') as inFile:
for line in inFile:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.find( 'Name') != -1:
        outfile.write(line + "\n")
    if line.find( 'ID#' ) != -1:
        outfile.write(line + "\n")
    if line.find( 'Term...:' ) != -1:
        outfile.write(line + "\n")
    if line.find( 'Amount Due' ) != -1:
        balance = line[:20]
        outfile.write(balance + "\n")
#        if line.startswith ('Reg No'):
#            flag=True
#            if flag:
#                data.append(line)
#            if line.strip().endswith('==='):
#                flag=False
#            outfile.write(data)
```

Comment: can you show an example of the text file and how you want your data be extracted (or expected output)?

Comment: Short answer: use a regex to split your string into chunks.

Comment: After `flag=True` you must (maybe after adding line to `data` or writing it to file) retrieve another `line` which can be done simply by iterating again through the loop. Your `if flag:` and `if line.strip().endswith('==='):` shouldn't be inside the other `if` because a new line isn't read there.

Answer (score 0):

Using the regex `(Name(.[^=]|\n|\r)*)+` on your data chunks it as you desire:

```
import re

with open('ARSP_MGRIFFIT_3728.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

matches = re.findall('(Name(.[^=]|\n|\r)*)+', data)
print(matches)
```

Explanation:

- `()+` - outer group, this finds multiple groups
- `Name` - ensures that the group must contain `Name`
- `(.[^=]|\n\r)*` Match any character except the `=` and newline characters

Applying this yields output such as:

```
Name: john smith
ID: 1234456
Amount Due: $0.00
Ref No   Date    Code   Charges  Payment   Balance
001234   12/6/18  BA     123.00   0        123.00
002345   12/7/18  DE    1000.00  1000.00   0
                Total:   1123.00 1000.00   123.00
                      <-- added to emphasize the whitespace matched up to the '='
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It makes sense but when I used your code I got this: [('Name: john smith', 'th')] . When I run it against my text file, I get the above for all names and I get "some" ID info.

Comment: @jbird It turns out that I tested this with Python 2, whose regex behavior is different to 3 in this case. Fixing

Comment: @jbird: fixed! I unescaped the `=` character

Comment: Do I have to install anything for regex? (windows 7) ..I'm still getting the same output.  Python 3.7.1  thanks for the help...never mind - I see that regex is part of Python.  I'll keep playing with this.  Again thanks!